# How to show or get line breakes in TinyMCE?

Tags: html, tinymce, break, line-breaks, tinymce-4

When I editing text in TinyMCE i can make line breakes (white lines), for example

```
<p>some text</p>
<p></p>
<p>some other text</p>
```

But when i saved it to server and shows article on the site it hides all `<p></p>`. But i need to equivalent behaviour if in editor I see white line i need it after save and show on site.

**The ways I saw to solve problem:**

1. Internally TinyMCE stores lines such `<p></p>` as `<p><br ... /></p>` but i can not get it after save...
   I can use `tinyMCE.get(contentid).getContent({ format: 'raw' });` but it breaks video and audio.
2. Or i can replace `<p></p>` on `<p><br /></p>` on server, but it is not working because it can be like `<p><strong></strong></p>` or `<p><span style="color:red"></strong></p>` many variants...
   Its difficult to parse them all.
3. To force TinyMCE to send me already prepaired content.
4. To make `<p></p>` visible in HTML, but how?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `format:raw` in your `getContent()` call?  That setting is typically not needed.

Comment: I'm using tinymce-4.4.3 version, and here i'm specifically removing empty <p> in the preprocess event like this: `setup: function (main) {main.on('PreProcess', function (e) {$.each($(e.node).find("section > p"), function (index, itm) {
                  if (itm.childNodes.length == 1 && itm.childNodes[0].nodeName == 'BR') {
                     $(itm).remove();
                  }
               });});}` Without this code, the empty <p>'s won't be removed by tinymce even when you save the html. Check on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made to show html empty `p` tags.

```
p:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:0px;
}
```

So, work for me perfect.